# new worker() in vscode extension has an incorrect file path with "vscode-webview://", not "https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/"

Tags: webassembly

Question:
Import wasm files succesfully into VSCode extension with "https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/Users/banma-1348/Desktop/wasm2/dist/browser/dist/magic_design_preview.js" as below, however, **for new worker()** the path is "**vscode-webview://**0ieb0s286o090htbegq5fhr57ugpt92lhv5pgl0tjvipjjl9mue1/magic_design_preview_wasm.worker.js"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tfkD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7ryO.png)

Step:

1. build wasm by ems-sdk with webWorker. (wasm works for WebGL)
2. build a vscode extension with wasm
3. run and debug
4. you will got error message as below:
   The code "var pthreadMainJs=locateFile("magic_design_preview_wasm.worker.js");PThread.unusedWorkers.push(**new Worker(pthreadMainJs)**)" come from ems-sdk.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaOtF.png)

Environment:
Version: 1.69.1 (Universal)
Commit: b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a
Date: 2022-07-12T08:21:51.333Z (1 day ago)
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.5.0

Comment: i don't know where "vscode-webview://" come from.

Comment: i found the vscode-webview, that's the pending-frame. my resource of extension are in the schema "vscodeFileResource", however, new a worker with the js file which find in shcema "vscodeWebview" ---> pending frame(index.html)